# How to ensure server has sent emails in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm running a load test in jmeter for a registration scenario. In that scenario, there is a situation where an OTP is sent for the email address provided. Is there a way to ensure that the email has been sent when running the test script. All the email addresses i use are dummy addresses getting from a CSV file. I do not wish to read the email or get any data from it. I simply am required to know if the emails has been sent when a certain http request is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "know if the emails has been sent" without actually receiving it so instead of "dummy" emails you can:

1. Set up a local mail server, i.e. [test-mail-server](https://github.com/eugenehr/test-mail-server) or real email address(es)
2. Configure your application to use this test mail server (or real mail server) for sending emails
3. Configure JMeter to read emails from this test mail server using [Mail Reader Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler). Check out [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733729-How-to-Create-a-JMeter-Script-to-Check-Email-During-Registration-AND-Grab-the-Confirmation-URL) article for more information.